# Image map tag doesnt work in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, image, dictionary, imagemap, area

the next code snipped is where I have problems,  the first 3  tags works well, but the 2 last doesnt work in Chrome and Firefox, in IExplorer works very well. Do you have any idea about it wrong or how resolve?

```
<div id="caratula" align="center">
    <img src="images/forma_acceso_sin_nav.png" border="0" usemap="#Map"/>

  <map name="Map" id="Map">

      <area shape="rect" coords="348,332,439,417" href="http://201.144.101.36/cotizador/" target="_blank"/>
      <area shape="rect" coords="470,363,508,398" href="http://201.144.101.45/onepage/" target="_blank" />
      <area shape="rect" coords="549,369,633,395" href="http://201.144.101.36/portaliswstudio/" target="_blank"/>

    <area shape="rect" coords="740,522,852,601" href="index.html" target="_self" alt="Pagina Principal" />

    <area shape="rect" coords="9,614,94,648" href="index.html" alt="buscas chamba" target="_blank" style="border:medium;"/>
    <area shape="rect" coords="110,616,142,647" href="index.html" alt="mailto" target="_blank"  />
  </map>
```

Comment: did you make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well , I have been searching information about it , and I found a table with the features browsers and compatibily with diferentes versions, I think that is the real problem, the reference is the next, maybe must be usefull for you .

http://haignet.co.uk/object-image-map.htm

Answer (score 1):

The usemap attribute shouldn't have a # in it.